# Secondary PCIe SSD not recognized at boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, pcie

I recently bought a Dell Precision 7530 laptop which came preinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04 on a 500GB SATA drive. Later I bought a 1TB PCIe SSD and installed it in a free slot in addition to the original SATA drive. I then installed Ubuntu 19.10 on the new SSD drive. The following is a screen shot from the Ubuntu USB installer:

[image]

The above screen shot shows that both disks were recognized at install time, and I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on the top most item from the above list: `/dev/nvme0n1 - 1.0 TB SSD`.

However, after installation completed and the machine restarted, there was no boot menu shown and it booted directly into the Ubuntu 16.04 on the SATA drive.

I then restarted the machine, and pressed F12 to enter the BIOS menu:

[image]

In the above screen shot, both the two items under the `UEFI BOOT` heading:

- `ubuntu`, and
- `UEFI ST500LM021-1KJ152, Partition 2`

refers to the preinstalled 500 GB SATA drive. 
Further if I enter BIOS setup, and then `Boot Sequence`, I get the following screen shot:

[image]

Also, I include a screen shot of the "Sata Operation" section from the BIOS setup:
[image]

Any suggestions what I should try here?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your machine as well, but setting up dual boot windows on my Dell XPS was a major pain. Your symptoms seems similar to what I experienced so I would suggest checking [this article](https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d) for BIOS settings and other tips.

Comment: Many with Dell need UEFI update & SSD firmware update, even if SSD is new. It looks like you already have AHCI on drives.

Comment: You need to enable RAID on in the BIOS