# Unable to boot Ubuntu from 2TB M2 PCIe NVMe SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, pcie, m2

I recently bought a Dell Precision 7530 laptop which came preinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04 on a 500GB SATA drive. Later I bought a 1TB M2 PCIe NVMe SSD and installed it in a free slot in addition to the original SATA drive.
[image]

I then installed Ubuntu 19.10 on the new SSD drive. This did however not work, see my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1184736/156688).

Later, I tried to physically remove the SATA drive and then it booted fine into Ubuntu 19.10 on the M2 PCIe SSD. Now I thought the problem was solved, and I bought a new 2TB M2 PCIe SSD from the same [brand](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evoplus/). I removed the 1TB SSD and replaced it with the 2TB SSD and then installed Ubuntu 19.10 (from USB):
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, when I restarted the computer I got "No bootable devices found.":
[image]

By pressing F2 I entered the BIOS:

[image]

which shows that the disk is present as "M.2 PCIe SSD-0". I find it very strange that the 1TB SSD can boot fine, whereas the 2TB SSD will not boot.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: You may have installed Ubuntu in the 2TB SSD in Legacy mode. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg) to see some differences in pictures for the Live USB in UEFI and Legacy modes.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks! This worked, fantastic!! When I press F12 at startup to enter boot mode selection screen, I previously chose the "Legacy external device boot" for the USB stick when installing Ubuntu, however I now chose "UEFI boot" instead and then reinstalled Ubuntu. When the installation finished, it booted fine into Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation problems with GRUB, can only install by reinstalling Windows in legacy mode but need to keep in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg)

Comment: @user68186 I am not sure if it answers the question, since I did not have a dual boot with Windows.

Comment: I am not sure either, the question is certainly different, but the answer is the same! ;-). I am hoping other reviewers will find a better question that already solves the same problem. Feel free to write your own answer. If no agrees that this is a duplicate, I will retract the close vote.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks again! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the boot device selection screen, you need to install Ubuntu from the USB using the "UEFI BOOT" option:

[image]

it will not work if you choose the "LEGACY EXTERNAL DEVICE BOOT" option:

[image]